# Load external page before navigating to it, rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a part of my website that involves navigating to an external site (revolutionary, eh?), and I'd like there to be no blank screen between the two sites. Is it possible to render the page, and then only navigate to it after it's ready? After it passed `$(document).ready`, although I don't think it's the same document anymore...

Let me know any ideas you guys have!

Comment: Not on two different domains. You can load the page on your server and ajax it in, but that will likely break functionality and have copyright issues. A nasty workaround could be to cache the next page in an iframe

Comment: Well, I actually own the other site. They're just on different servers. Well, probably. I host them both on heroku. So they may be on the same server. But definitely different domains.

Comment: @JShoe Then, for all intents and purposes, they are on different servers. Heroku spins up different dynos as per your apps' needs, but they are highly unlikely to be literally on the same hardware.

Comment: Right on. So with that in mind, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Even if sites are on differents domains, this jquery code seems to run  :

```
$('iframe').css('display', 'none').load(function(){
    $(this).css('display', 'block')
})
```

And with javascript :

```
iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
iframe.style.display = 'none'
iframe.onload = function() {
    iframe.style.display = 'block'
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to write that in coffeescript?

Comment: Is it possible to zoom out in an iframe?

Comment: If I try to put that into a coffeescript file, it would crash. I'll have to convert is myself. Not a big deal, just wondering if you were more familiar than I.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't use coffeescript. Otherwise, you can do that with only simple javascript.

Comment: Javascript isn't simple. Hence coffeescript.